# How can I make a chipView ractangle

Tags: java, android, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

I am using a simple `chipView`. There is a little problem, the default shape for chip is oval. I want to make it rectangle and add a little radius to corners? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways.

The fastest way is the use of `app:chipCornerRadius` attribute in the layout.

The 2nd way allows you to draw different kind of shapes using the **`app:shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/buttomShape0"
        ../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="buttomShape0">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution

```
    app:chipCornerRadius=""
```